# Adding browseui.dll to the project

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, dll

I'm trying to develop an add-on for IE, and I want to add browseui.dll to my project, but I get this error message

A reference to "C:\BROWSEUI.DLL" could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM componenet.

Does anyone have idea what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to add it to your project.  You just want to add it to the list of libraries you link to, if you are actually using stuff it provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your component in your `registery base`. you can use `RegSrv32` tool, before use

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx